# Running ansible playbooks programmatically using celery

Tags: ansible, celery

I'm trying to run some ansible playbooks programmatically with celery, but it doesn't work. Meaning I get the name of the tasts in the playbook, but nothing happens. If I'm starting celery with --pool=solo ... it works.
Using --pool=prefork doesn't work, but it also does not complain about anything.

Any ideas how can I overcome this thing or find more info ?
I've found that at v3, celery, had some issues running ansible programmatically.

Comment: Are you aware of [awx and/or tower](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme), which is quite literally trying to solve that problem and a ton more?

Comment: Yes, I am. In the project I'm working on I have this setup. I don't want to introduce tower just to run 2 playbooks.

Comment: I am also running into the same issue, adding --pool=solo worked, did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have a similar setup which works with -P solo but Ansible is rather slow... and thought increasing the pool might improve the speed..

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1` before starts Celery-worker
OR start Celery with this parameter `-O OPTIMIZATION`.